# When are static variables initialized in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Consider the following code

```
class Foo:
    i = 1 # initialization
    def __init__(self):
        self.i += 1

t = Foo()
print(t.i)
```

When exactly does the initialization of **i** take place? **Before** the execution of the **init** method or **after** it?

Comment: That's a *class attribute*, it's defined when the class is. You can access `Foo.i` prior to instantiation.

Comment: Looking at Foo.i vs t.i may be informative: https://ideone.com/NPWMSX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before.

The `__init__` method isn't run until `Foo` is instantiated. `i=1` is run whenever the class definition is encountered in the code

You can see this by adding print statements:

```
print('Before Foo')
class Foo:
    i = 1
    print(f'Foo.i is now {i}')
    
    def __init__(self):
        print('Inside __init__')
        self.i += 1
        print(f'i is now {self.i}')
print('After Foo')

print('Before __init__')
foo = Foo()
print('After __init__')
```

which prints:

```
Before Foo
Foo.i is now 1
After Foo
Before __init__
Inside __init__
i is now 2
After __init__
```

---

Notice however, that your `self.i += 1` **does not** modify the class attribute `Foo.i`.

```
foo.i # This is 2
Foo.i # This is 1
```

Comment: `i = 1` *would* be run in the local scope, but `i += 1` just raises an error

Comment: @MadPhysicist He added `self`, so it's not an error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about unnamed functions (f''). Like it a lot.

Comment: @Dan That is what's commonly called f-strings. It's for string formatting. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute is initialized the first time you use the ClassName in the source code, also you use the class attribute in the code by doing `ClassMethod.attribute`

```
class Foo:
    i = 1 # initialization
    def __init__(self):
        #Use ClassName.attribute to access class attribute
        Foo.i += 1

#I used the Name of the class here, Foo.i will be 1
print(Foo.i)
#1

#Instantiated Foo
t = Foo()

#Value of i changes to 2
print(t.i)
#2
```

Comment: Hi @chepner, thanks for the edit but should it be `static class attribute` instead?

Comment: No, the only thing in Python with "static" in its name is the static method.

Comment: Yes a class method or an attribute is inherently `static`

Comment: Define "static" in Python.

Comment: That is something I don't have an answer @chepner Could you explain or provide an example :)